# What would be the optimal structure for a fixed availability schedule?

Tags: mysql, database, calendar, schedule

I'm setting up a calendar on which users can indicate when they are available. The calendar is split up in 3 time slots per day, for 7 days a week (monday-morning, monday-afternoon, monday-evening).

I'm a bit stuck on what the best way would be to store this in my database. I've thought about doing:

*start_date*

*end_date*

*user_id*

**or**

*timeslot*

*user_id*

**or**

*user_id&*
*mon1*
*mon2*
*mon3*
*...*
*sun3*
creating 21 columns doesn't seem optimal, but it does make the availability query very easy.

I would like to keep some flexibility in defining the hours for the slots. The second one appears to give me this, as I can just define the hours per day afterwards.

In the end I have to be able to look up who is available on 2019-02-01 13:00:00 - 2019-02-01 17:15:00. These dates will not correspond with the timeslots.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3 fields to store this information,

```
slot_date - to store date of slot like 2018-12-17, 2018-12-18, etc
slot_time - to store time slot like 13:00:00, 15:00:00, etc
user_id - to store user identifier
```

Let's say your sample data for 2 users with these fields will look somewhat like this,

```
slot_date    slot_time    user_id
---------------------------------
2018-12-17    14:00:00      1
2018-12-17    17:00:00      2
```

You can easily get the availability of the users for a given time slot. For instance, you want to fetch today's availability for afternoon slot ( considering 1 pm to 4 pm is evening slot ), which can be retrieved by following query,

```
SELECT slot_date, slot_time, user_id
FROM tbl_slot 
WHERE slot_date = '2018-12-17'
AND slot_time BETWEEN '13:00:00' AND '15:00:00'
```

Similarly, you can change the `slot_time` clause in the query to work for morning and evening slots.

**Update**

Based on OP's requirement, if a user selects a day and a slot it will be applicable for every month/year. Based on it, you an eliminate the `slot_date` column and use `day_of_week` that will store integer values from 1 to 7 i.e. (Sun to Sat)

```
day_of_week    slot_time    user_id
-----------------------------------
    2           14:00:00      1
    2           17:00:00      2
```

Then, the query to get all afternoon availability will be,

```
SELECT day_of_week, slot_time, user_id
FROM tbl_slot 
WHERE day_of_week = '2'
AND slot_time BETWEEN '13:00:00' AND '15:00:00'
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but the availability is not specific per week. Users just indicate that they are available every monday afternoon (or another period in the week)

Comment: Yes, it will still work for any day of the month or year. Depending on your requirement, you can query with date range too and fetch the availability.

Comment: Ok, but it shouldn't store any specific dates. The approach could work if you replace slot_date with day_of_week I guess

Comment: If a user say Monday in the evening, does it mean his availability is on every Monday evening of every month/year?

Comment: Yes! It's more like a general preference instead of a very precise indication.

Comment: Perfect, then day of week will work. Use integer for day of week. Have updated my answer. You can check it out.

Comment: Great, this seems very efficient. I will only change times to some integer representing a certain slot time, times are arbitrary for this purpose.

Comment: Cool, if it helped you may upvote and accept the answer, so other with similar questions can find it useful in the future :)